# How to parse JSON response to POJO class in android?

Tags: android, json

I got response from a webservice (See response below) and I want to convert it into POJO class object. I know Gson library for android for parsing JSON to VO (Value object) object, I used this but it gives me null value in every field (as code stated below) but I want only a few of fields from response like "dob" and "password" and my response is to completed (as shown below) so how can i parse this response? Thanks in advance.

```
Respose: {"row0":"{\"id\":\"1\",\"password\":\"1234\",\"group_id
\":\"1\",\"dob\":\"1981-10-01\",\"gender\":\"f\",\"marital_status\":\"single\",\"children\":
\"\",\"phone\":\"\",\"mobile\":\"\",\"allow_mobile\":\"0\",\"interests\":\"\"}}
```

Parsing Code :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
 UserDetailVO vo = gson.fromJson(result, UserDetailVO.class);
Logger.log("Response", vo.toString());
```

My UseDetailVO Contain only two String field "password" and "dob" and its getter setter method and overriden "toString()" method that prints both value.

Comment: i think your `json` is not valid, please test your `json` on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan: You are right i tested in your given URL but now how can i make it right by programmatically?

Comment: Yes, how to convert above string into right JSON ?

Comment: i'm really sorry, i don't have time for that, please use http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply i will work on that thank you so much your reply.

Comment: @Hitesh542 Why you need to fix the Json string from your side? Webservice should return valid json, while returning json they should properly serialize the response using some library. You can try with a regular expression to remove the escape characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
***JSON TO POJO** 
    http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/   -- open this Site Create pojo class
    Target language:
    Java 
    Source type:
    JSON  
     Annotation style:
    Gson  
    Include getters and setters    Check
    Preview 
    -------------------------------- 
      Model Class to pass other class 
    Parcelable*
```

Comment: Though it solved your problem, it is not a proper solution. The webservice you are calling, is it written by you? If it is written by you, you should correct the response format by serializing objects using JSON library. You can refer Google's [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library documentation.

Comment: @Uttam: Actually in my case webservice is not written by me and i have to manage response on my side no other way so for this situation i solved this problem.